# How to do word breaks inside a Visualforce page that is rendered as PDF?

Tags: apex, visualforce, css, table

Hi now I made a table using table-layout: fixed. However, the page is displayed beyond the box, rather than passing the table line as shown in the image. I searched these parts and tried using word-break: break-all or other css, but it didn't work at all. Is there anyone who can help me T.T

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" applyBodyTag="false"  renderAs="pdf" standardStylesheets="false" controller="TestContoller">

<head>
    <style>
              @page {
            size: A4 landscape;
            margin-right: 7mm;
            margin-left: 7mm;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            font-family: Helvetica;
            height : 100%;
            @top-center {
                content: "";
            } 
           
        }
            body {
            font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
              padding-top : 50px;
          
        }
        caption {
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 40px;
            background-color: #4A86E8;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            
        }
        .my_table{]
            width:100%;
            height : 100%;
            border: 1px solid;
            
            border-collapse : collapse;
        }
        td,th {
        height:70px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align : center;
        }
        
        .tr1 th {
            font-size:18px;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        .tr1 td {
            color : blue;
        font-size : 15px;
        }
        
        .tr2 td {
            font-size:13px;
            font-weight:bold;
            height:70px;
            background-color : #D9EAD3
        }
        .tr3 th {
            font-size:12px;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        .tr3 td{
            color:blue;
        }
        .tr4 th {
            font-size:12px;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        .tr4 td{
            color:blue;
        }
        .tr5 th {
            font-size:15px;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        .tr5 td{
            color:red;
        }
        .page-break{
          display:block;
          page-break-after:always;

        }
    </style> 
</head>
```

<apex:repeat value="{!Result}" var="record" id="theRepeat">

RESULT
  
    
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
  
    
      (Date)
      
        {!record['IncFptDate__c']}
        
        
(Client name)
      {!record['IncFptDisCom__c']}
        
(Sample No.)
      {!record['IncFptSampleNo__c']}
        
    
     
    
      (Flash point) (degC)
      pH
      (Toxic gas possibility)
      (Calorific value) (kcal/kg)
      (Other ccomments)
    
    
        (Threshold)
        
        (Threshold)
        
        (Threshold)
        
        {!record['IncCal__c']}
        
        
    
        (Analysis)
        {!record['IncFptFlashPoint__c']}
        (Analysis)
        {!record['IncFptpH__c']}
        (Analysis)
        {!record['CheckToxisGas__c']}
              
  
    (Flash point)
            
            {!record['FlashPoint_text']}
            
            (Special comments)
       
       
         pH 
         {!record['FlashPoint_ph_text']}
         {!record['IncFptNote__c']}   
       
       
            (Toxic gas possibility)
           {!record['FlashPoint_Toxis_text']}

</apex:repeat>

</apex:page>

```
public with sharing class TestContoller {
public String param1 { get; set; }
public List<String> printIds { get; set; }
public List<Map<String, Object>> Result { get; set; }



public TestContoller() {
    this.param1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('param1');
    initializeResult();
}

private void initializeResult() {
    Map<String, Object> paramDetails = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(this.param1);

    if (paramDetails.containsKey('ids') && paramDetails.get('ids') instanceof List<Object>) {
        this.printIds = new List<String>();
        for (Object idObj : (List<Object>)paramDetails.get('ids')) {
            if (idObj instanceof String) {
                this.printIds.add((String)idObj);
            }
        }
    }

    if (this.printIds != null && !this.printIds.isEmpty()) {
        List<IncFingerPrintTest__c> TestRecords = [
            SELECT Id, IncFptDate__c, IncFptDisCom__c, IncFptDisCom__r.name, IncFptSampleNo__c,
                   IncFptFlashPoint__c, IncFptpH__c, IncCal__c, CheckToxisGas__c,IncFptNote__c 
            FROM IncFingerPrintTest__c
            WHERE Id IN :this.printIds
        ];

        this.Result = new List<Map<String, Object>>();

        for (IncFingerPrintTest__c record : TestRecords) {
            Map<String, Object> detailMap = new Map<String, Object>{
                'IncFptDate__c' => record.IncFptDate__c != null ?  (record.IncFptDate__c).year()+' - '+(record.IncFptDate__c).month()+' - '+ (record.IncFptDate__c).day(): 'ㅤ',
                'IncFptDisCom__c' => record.IncFptDisCom__r.name != null ? String.valueOf(record.IncFptDisCom__r.name) : 'ㅤ',
                'IncFptSampleNo__c' => record.IncFptSampleNo__c != null ? String.valueOf(record.IncFptSampleNo__c) : 'ㅤ',
                'IncCal__c' => record.IncCal__c != null ? String.valueOf(record.IncCal__c) : 'ㅤ',
                'IncFptFlashPoint__c' => record.IncFptFlashPoint__c != null ? String.valueOf(record.IncFptFlashPoint__c) : 'ㅤ',
                'IncFptpH__c' => record.IncFptpH__c != null ? String.valueOf(record.IncFptpH__c) : 'ㅤ',
                'IncFptNote__c' => record.IncFptNote__c != null ? String.valueOf(record.IncFptNote__c) : 'ㅤ','CheckToxisGas__c' => record.CheckToxisGas__c != null ? String.valueOf(record.CheckToxisGas__c) : 'ㅤ'
            };

            if (record.IncFptFlashPoint__c != null && record.IncFptFlashPoint__c <= 22.5) {
                detailMap.put('FlashPoint', 'font-size: 15px; padding: 10px; text-align: center; background-color: #f4c7c3;');
                detailMap.put('FlashPoint_text', 'No');
            } else {
                detailMap.put('FlashPoint', 'ㅤ');
                detailMap.put('FlashPoint_text', 'ㅤ');
            }
            if (record.IncFptpH__c != null && record.IncFptpH__c <= 3) {
                detailMap.put('FlashPoint_ph_text', 'a');
            } else if (record.IncFptpH__c != null && record.IncFptpH__c >= 7) {
                detailMap.put('FlashPoint_ph_text', 'b');
            }else{
                detailMap.put('FlashPoint_ph_text', 'OK');
            }
            if (record.CheckToxisGas__c != null && record.CheckToxisGas__c == 0) {
                detailMap.put('FlashPoint_Toxis_text','OK');
            }else{
                detailMap.put('FlashPoint_Toxis_text', 'ㅤ');
            }

            this.Result.add(detailMap);
        }
    }
}
```

}[image]

Thanks :)